# Issue charting pandas dataframe to bargraph with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Newbie to python and programming in general here.

I am doing a project where I am trying to take one of our capacity reports for our storage clusters and make an actual useful report instead of just a bunch of numbers for our capacity team.

I have been trying to parse a csv into Pandas and then create a bar graph from the data.

I have been able to read the CSV and successfully parse the data I want, but am having trouble getting it to chart in matplotlib with a horizontal bar graph.

This is where I am at so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Avoid truncating of columns and rows

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# Read from csv
df = pd.read_csv(r,<filename>.csv

# Delete unecessary lines

df.drop(df.index[[0,1,2]], inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Group Name', 'Pool Count', 'Total Capacity', 'Free Space', 'In Use Space', '', 'Delegated Space', 'Reserved Space']

# df1 == space consumed. Output is similar to 12.5 TB
# df2 == Cluster Names. Output is just a name similar to PHX-ESX-9900
df1 = df.iloc[0:39,4]
df2 = df.iloc[0:39, 0]

# Chart attempts

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
df.plot.barh(df.iloc[0:39,4],df.iloc[0:39,0]color="#444444", label="Capacity")
plt.legend()
plt.title(Capacity Report")
plt.xlabel("Used Capacity")
plt.ylabel("Group Names")
plt.tight_layout()
```

Any advice on how to chart this? I have been banging my head on the wall all day.

Comment: You need to provide a self-contained, runnable example and explain what the problem is.  The code you posted isn't even syntactically valid.

Comment: Which columns and rows do you want to plot? All of them?

Comment: Trying to plot just the 1st and 5th columns. 1st column is group names, 5th is space used. Rows 1-39.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look at this link to get an idea of how to ask questions. better questions = better answers :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Guys! I've only been working with Python on and off for a few weeks, and pandas for about a day or so. This does exactly what I need. You guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [i+1 for i in range(5)],
                   'col_2': ["x"]*5,
                   'col_3': ["x"]*5,
                   'col_4': ["x"]*5,
                   'col_5': [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(5)],
                   'col_6': ["x"]*5,
                   })
print(df)
   col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4  col_5 col_6
0      1     x     x     x      1     x
1      2     x     x     x      6     x
2      3     x     x     x      1     x
3      4     x     x     x      5     x
4      5     x     x     x      5     x
```

Lets say you wanted to plot only rows `1` through `3`. You can do that with the following

```
plt.barh(y = df["col_1"].values[1:4], width = df["col_5"].values[1:4])
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib Plot]